# Importing a .Rdata file in .NET

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I'm quite novice with R and I don't quite understand a few simple things.
I need to load an .Rdata file using C#.NET.
I've installed the R.NET library and I've initialize the engine without any issues.
What I'm struggling is how to import a file , load its content into a dataframe and from that point manipulate the dataframe.
I've also checked the internet but I go stuck.
The following image was taken while following steps I found online. Even the count is incorrect between the Rdata file and the dataframe
Any help would be highly appreciated.
I will also attach an image of the .Rdata file from the R GUI
[image]

[image]

Comment: I recommend to save the file as either csv or feather instead. RDS/RData files are not meant to be importet into sth. else like R. If you want to use R bnindings for c#, use R function `load("foo.RData")` isntead of `read.table("foo.RData")`

Comment: I've tried the above way. It does indeed load the object as CharacterVector. How would one access this object and retrieve the data?

Comment: The last commit to `rdotnet` was one year ago. Why not just simply write an R script, test it with RStudio and then use a system shell call from c# to call it? What part of the calculation must be done in c#? Which data structure do you have in c# to match the data? list of objects?